# Progress indication from server to client wcf-c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I have a client server application. Client will send a data to the server thru wcf call. But server takes around 1 minute to process the data. So i want to get the progress from the server to client. How do i it with wcf service. Please provide me with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the service contain another method for polling progress and call both methods with an identifier, for example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<int> dataToProcess = something....
    int requestID = 1;
    MyService.MyMethodToProcess(dataToProcess, requestID);
}
```

Another polling thread (updating a UI or whatever):

```
double precentage = MyService.PollMyMethodToProcess(requestID);
myUIProgressBar.Update(precentage);
```

MyMethodToProcess example:

```
public void MyMethodToProcess(List<int> data, int requestID)
{
    idToProgress.Add(requestID, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
    {
        prossessData(data.ElementAt(i));
        idToProgress[requestID] += 100/(double)data.Count; //Updates the progress.
    }
}

ConcurrentDictionary<int, double> idToProgress = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, double>();
```

And in the poll method:

```
public double PollMyMethodToProcess(int requestID)
{
    return idToProgress[requestID];
}
```

The right way to do it would be the service pushing the progress through the normal communication with the client though it will be much more difficult and not cost-effective...

Answer (score 0):

Provide a Call back contract so your service can call back your client when the stage of the process has changed for example an amount of bytes has been saved to a file.